# How count the number of records in a table and print the result using Querybuilder in Yii

Tags: sql, yii, query-builder

I'm new to the Yii Framework, and I'm trying to run a query so I can count the number of records in a table and print it in my index.php (under view/site/index.php)

Here my sql code

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM entidades WHERE sectores_id=2
```

I've searched and found about Querybuilder in Yii but I can't make it work.

Any help??

Comment: I need to print a number of records in my companies table, but don't know how? When I used your code I got error msg (i.e companies not found). I placed it on my Site/index.php. Any help will be useful. Thanks...
Here's my code:- <?php $count2 = companies::model()->countByAttributes(array());
                echo $count2;
            ?>

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem with the folowing code. In my view/site/index.php i've added.

```
<?php $count2 = Entidades::model()->countByAttributes(array('sectores_id' => '2'));
                echo $count2;
            ?>
```